# Updating java code from server

Tags: java, android

I have an app that has an activity which allow users to download PDF files by selecting a PDF and clicking the download button.

The issue is: I don't want to always ask users to update the app when there's a new material available.

Is there a way I can update the **.java** code without always asking users to update the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong design point.

You have probably hardcoded the PDF / file names in your Java application.
When these values are supposed to change, then well: don't hardcode them.

Instead you create a server side service that *lists* the available PDFs. And then your app uses that service in order to acquire that information.
Anything that is "dynamic" must not be hardcoded in your app itself. Instead your app knows how to fetch that piece of information from somewhere.

When the source code of your application changes, your users have to upgrade the app. It is that simple. The other way round: if you know about "changes" to your app that need to work without upgrading the app, then well: you have to design the whole app around that requirement.

A first starting point / further reading: see [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-from-scratch-using-rest-apis--cms-27117).

Comment: I now understand your answer perfectly. Can I get a code sample of your answer?